# jQuery UI datepicker performance on select

Tags: jquery, performance, jquery-ui, datepicker

I've got an instance of a jQuery UI datepicker here:

https://app.shvitz.com.au/en/listings/11-yoga-in-the-park

Wait a couple of seconds for it to load on the right side of the page.

I'm experiencing some strange performance issues when selecting dates. You can view the source in calendar.js, but this is the relevant part:

```
function onSelect(date, instance) {
    var mDate = moment(date, "DD-MM-YYYY");
    var $timeslots = renderTimeslots(mDate);
    $container.children('.timeslots-container').remove();
    $container.append($timeslots);
}

function renderTimeslots(date) {
    if (!date) date = moment(calendar.datepicker('getDate').getTime());

    var times = availabilities.filter(function (a) {
        return moment(a.start_time).startOf('day').isSame(date.startOf('day'));
    });

    function availToPrice(a) {
        function getPrice(a) {
            if (!api.getShared()) return 66;

            var left = a.capacity - a.bookings;
            switch (left) {
                case 1:
                    return 20;
                case 2:
                    return 25;
                case 3:
                    return 35;
                case 4:
                    return 35;
            }
        }

        var ret = '$' + (getPrice(a) * (a.duration / 60)).toFixed(2);
        var people = a.bookings + ' people';
        if (a.bookings == 0) {
            people = 'Empty';
        } else if (a.bookings == 1) {
           people = '1 person';
        }
        return ret + ' - ' + people;
    }

    var timeslots = times.map(function (t) {
        return $('<div class="clearfix switch-field"><input id="' + t.start_time + '" name="calendar-timeslots" type="radio" value="' + t.start_time + '"/> <label for="' + t.start_time + '" style="margin:0" class="btn btn-success calendar-timeslot">' + moment(t.start_time).format('hh:mm a') + '(' + availToPrice(t) + ')' +
            '</label></div>');
    });
    if (onChange !== null) {
        timeslots.forEach(function ($t) {
            $t.children('input').click(function () {
                onChange({
                    'shared': api.getShared(),
                    'time': api.getTime()
                });
            });
        });
    }
    var $cont = $('<div class="timeslots-container"></div>');
    $cont.append(timeslots);
    return $cont;
}
```

When you click on a date you'll notice a delay before it changes colour to blue and the timeslots are rendered below. I would estimate the delay to be at least a few hundred milliseconds. However, when I use `console.time` to measure the time taken in the `onSelect` function it's typically around 20ms, and the worst I saw was 60ms. Where is this additional delay coming from, and how can I fix it?

Comment: If you check performance in dev tool you will notice that over 1s is spent on bubbling a click event. Can you make [http://jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net) with that calendar?

Answer (score 0):

Jquery ui actually has delay for proces, so if you want to optimize your ui, you should use html5 no jquery.